# Database Exception in Slick 3.0 while batch insert

Tags: postgresql, scala, slick-3.0

While inserting thousands of records per five seconds through batch insert in slick 3 I am getting

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: sorry, too many clients already
```

My data access layer looks like :

```
val db: CustomPostgresDriver.backend.DatabaseDef = Database.forURL(url, user=user, password=password, driver= jdbcDriver)



 override def insertBatch(rowList: List[T#TableElementType]): Future[Long] = {
    val res = db.run(insertBatchQuery(rowList)).map(_.head.toLong).recover{ case ex:Throwable=> RelationalRepositoryUtility.handleBatchOperationErrors(ex)}
//db.close()
        res
      }

  override def insertBatchQuery(rowList: List[T#TableElementType]): FixedSqlAction[Option[Int], NoStream, Write] = {
    query ++= (rowList)
  }
```

closing the connection in insert batch has no effect...it still gives the same error.

I am calling insert batch from my code like this :

```
val temp1 = list1.flatMap { li =>
        Future.sequence(li.map { trip =>
            val data = for {
              tripData <- TripDataRepository.insertQuery( trip.tripData)
              subTripData <- SubTripDataRepository.insertBatchQuery(getUpdatedSubTripDataList(trip.subTripData, tripData.id))
            } yield ((tripData, subTripData))
            val res=db.run(data.transactionally)
          res
//db.close()
        })
      }
```

if i close the connection after my work here as you can see in commented code i get error :

```
java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Task slick.backend.DatabaseComponent$DatabaseDef$$anon$2@6c3ae2b6 rejected from java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@79d2d4eb[Terminated, pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 1]
```

After calling the method without Future.sequence like this :

```
 val temp1 =list.map { trip =>
          val data = for {
            tripData <- TripDataRepository.insertQuery( trip.tripData)
            subTripData <- SubTripDataRepository.insertBatchQuery(getUpdatedSubTripDataList(trip.subTripData, tripData.id))
          } yield ((tripData, subTripData))
          val res=db.run(data.transactionally)
          res
      }
```

I still got too many clients error...

Comment: "*sorry, too many clients already*" means you are opening many, many connections but you never close them.

Comment: Can you post how you are calling insertBatch and little bit more sorrouding code ? As suggested by @a_horse_with_no_name, the error means you are opening one too many connections.

Comment: li.map { trip =>
            val data = for {
              tripData <- TripDataRepository.insertQuery( trip.tripData)// (TripDataRepository.query returning TripDataRepository.query.map(obj => obj) += trip.tripData)
              subTripData <- SubTripDataRepository.insertBatchQuery(getUpdatedSubTripDataList(trip.subTripData, tripData.id))
            } yield ((tripData, subTripData))
            val res=db.run(data.transactionally)

Comment: this is how i am calling the insert batch method ...even if i try close the connection in insert batch after doing my work...it's still the same error

Comment: Can you verify how many connections does your postgres db allows ? Please use this command on postgres "show max_connections"

Comment: max connections is 100

Comment: One more request can you change form future.sequence to flatmap. Just to run the actions sequentially rather than parallel from the future.sequence ?

Comment: I need to use parallel executions so I am using futures ,  I can't go with flatmap. In slick 3 ...everything will return futures

Comment: I believe future.sequence is executing your queries parallelly which is exhausting the connection. Wanted to work without it to verify that that the case. Its more like if you know where the error is you can move forward to fix it.

Comment: may be that is the case...i will test executing it without futures

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80254/discussion-between-archana-and-biswanath).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root of this problem is that you are spinning up an unbounded list of `Future` simultaneously, each connecting to the database - one per entry in `list`.

This can be solved by running your inserts in serial, forcing each insert batch to depend on the previous:

```
// Empty Future for the results. Replace Unit with the correct type - whatever
// "res" is below.
val emptyFuture = Future.successful(Seq.empty[Unit])
// This will only insert one at a time. You could use list.sliding to batch the
// inserts if that was important.
val temp1 = list.foldLeft(emptyFuture) { (previousFuture, trip) =>
  previousFuture flatMap { previous =>
    // Inner code copied from your example.
    val data = for {
      tripData <- TripDataRepository.insertQuery(trip.tripData)
      subTripData <- SubTripDataRepository.insertBatchQuery(getUpdatedSubTripDataList(trip.subTripData, tripData.id))
    } yield ((tripData, subTripData))
    val res = db.run(data.transactionally)
    previous :+ res
  }
}
```